# How does MDB on WildFly consume messages from JBOSS 5.1

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly, bridge

How to configure MDB on WildFly to read JMS messages from other cluster running JBOSS Messaging on JBOSS 5.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a JMS bridge : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration#Messagingconfiguration-JMSBridge